# Windows 8 Metro Equivalent to System.Windows.Media.DrawingGroup and ImageDrawing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a WPF .NET 3.5 app that draws transparent tile layers on top of one another using an ImageDrawing and DrawingGroup.

I'm trying to convert this for Windows 8 using Metro.

Microsoft's porting overview at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136.aspx suggests changing System.Windows namespace references to Windows.UI.Xaml.  This helped with most things, but I haven't found ImageDrawing and DrawingGroup and didn't find any mention of them in Windows.UI.Xaml.

Do they exist in Metro?  If so, where, or if not, what can I use to accomplish an equivalent task?

Here's an example code I'm using:

```
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image img = mapGrid.Children.Cast<Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image>().First(e => Grid.GetRow(e) == 2 && Grid.GetColumn(e) == 4);

    if (img != null)
    {
        Uri back = new Uri("tiles/green.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageDrawing background = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageDrawing(new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(back), new Rect(0, 0, 32, 32));
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.DrawingGroup myDrawingGroup = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.DrawingGroup();
        myDrawingGroup.Children.Add(background);
        // Add one or more foreground tiles here, removed for brevity.
    }
```

Fully qualified namespaces for clarity (I hope).

Comment: Nope. No ImageDrawing, DrawingGroups or many other features in Metro

Comment: Any recommended way to render transparent images stacked on top of each other in the same location?

Comment: if that is all you need then just put multiple image controls inside a Grid.